# Time differences wrong calculation

Tags: javascript, date

```
function parseDate(s){
    var parts = s.split('/')
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0])
}

function calcDaysBetween(startDate, endDate){
    return Math.floor((endDate-startDate)/86400000);
}

function yarro(){
    var startDate = parseDate($('#pickupdate').val());
    var endDate = parseDate($('#dropoffdate').val());
    var days = calcDaysBetween(startDate, endDate);
    $('#newp').html('Days Count: <b>'+days);
}
```

> 31/3/2012 , 1/4/2012
> Days Count: 0 //wrong

or

> 31/1/2012 , 1/2/2012
> Days Count: -1 //wrong

> 1/1/2012 , 2/1/2012
> Days Count: 1 //ok

Why?

Comment: Months start with `0`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Months in JavaScript's `Date()` are numbered from `0` (January) to `11` (December). Keep that in mind.

Comment: Well, instead from `1` to `12`, months go from `0` to `11`. Meaning instead of `3`, March is `2`... this should give you a clue ;)

Comment: i am not using months or days dynamicly,its all manuel

Comment: @TLS: There are things worse in life.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing that JS months are 0-based is *very important* to this.  Your code is parsing the date 31/1/2012 into 31 *February* 2012, which is technically an invalid date but is interpreted as 2 March 2012 (the 2nd because 2012 is a leap year).  What you need to do is subtract `1` from the `parts[1]` value before passing it to the `Date` constructor.

You are getting -1 days between 31/1/2012 and 1/2/2012 because those dates are interpreted as 31 February 2012 (2 March 2012) and 1 March 2012.  When you subtract those dates, you get a -1-day difference.

You are getting 0 days between 31/3/2012 and 1/4/2012 because those dates are interpreted as 31 April 2012 (1 May 2012) and 1 May 2012, which are the same date, resulting in a 0-day difference.

You are getting 1 day between 1/1/2012 and 2/1/2012 because those dates are interpreted as 1 February 2012 and 2 February 2012, resulting in a 1-day difference.